# How to Install Skype domain-wide

Tags: windows-server-2008, automated-install, skype

You know Live Messenger is over and we have to migrate to Skype. I got two choices to do that on 40+ computers under the domain.

1. Give standard users permission to install software.
2. Automatically/centrally install the software.

Can I do the 2nd choice and how?

Comment: You don't HAVE to migrate to Skype. You could: A. Stop using instant messaging. B. Use an alternate product, like GoogleTalk.

Answer (score 2):

you can use Active Directory Software Distribution for this. The Skype Business Version is delivered with a MSI Package. There are .adm Extensions for configuring Skype via GPO available too.

have a look at http://download.skype.com/share/business/guides/skype-it-administrators-guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download the msi Installer and deploy it by GroupPolicy. You can set the permission by setting it up as Computer Policy.